# Why are "joking aside" and "six hours ago" Postpositional Clauses?

Tags: syntax-trees

This [webpage](https://parentingpatch.com/adjunct-adverbial-english-grammar/) outlines the "four grammatical forms that can function as the adjunct adverbial". In the [tree underneath](https://parentingpatch.com/using-postpositional-phrases-adjunct-adverbials/), I agree that "aside and "ago" are postpositions, but please see the question in the title.

1. Why isn't the red node (not the one underneath) a Verb Phrase?
2. Why isn't this orange node a Noun Phrase or Determiner Phrase?

> [image]

In [Adverb Clause as Adjunct Adverbial](https://parentingpatch.com/using-adverb-clauses-adjunct-adverbials/), isn't the Clause categorized as Adverb as "unless" is the first word to appear in that Clause?

> [image]

Comment: because *ago* and *aside* were infix, that is regular prefixes like *besides*, but the coordinated term was elided and now it's idiomatic? Just guessing, hours before [someone posts an answer or the question is closed for showing lack of research].

Comment: The PP "joking aside" is a supplement. The PP "six hours ago" is a temporal adjunct in clause structure -- it doesn't contain a verb, so it can hardly be a clause.